# Python working with two list generating new lists with values

Tags: python

I have this two list:

```
occurrence = [2,1,3,1,4,...]
dates = [2.4, 1.5, 30, 5.6,4, 8, 32, ...]
```

result:

```
list1 = [2.4, 1.5]
list2 = [3.0]
list3 = [30, 5.6,4]
...
```

I do not know how large is each list, but I need to extract the values of dates list, depending of the value of each item in occurrence and put in news lists. I am new in python, thank you for your help

Comment: Where did `list2`'s `3.0` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice array by using `array[START:STOP]` (See more samples it [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)):

```
>>> p = 0
>>> for i in occurrence:
...     print dates[p:p+i]
...     p += i

[2.4, 1.5]
[30]
[5.6, 4, 8]
[32]
[]
```

It doesn't depend which array is longer, it will work anyway. as you can see on 4th iteration you get an empty array because nothing left in `dates` array.

Comment: thank you my friend !!! that's help me a lot I just need to give it a name to each new list

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this will suffice:

```
previous = 0
lists = []
for quantity in ocurrence:
    lists.append(dates[previous:previous+quantity])
    previous += quantity
print lists
```